# Method calculations/arguments in Java

Tags: java, methods

I have to create a virtual coffee shop where the user enters their order number, how many of that order they want, calculate the subtotal and the discount, etc. The whole point of this is that the process's divided into various methods. Most of the methods are pretty simple, but I'm having trouble with the computeSubTotal method. I have to initialize subtotal in the main method to make this work, but when the subtotal's calculated in computeSubTotal, it always ends up being zero. Sorry if this seems stupid, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CoffeeShopWithMethods
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String user_name;
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter your name: ");
        user_name = user_input.next();
        System.out.println("\nWelcome to the Java Byte Code Coffee Shop, " + user_name + "!");

        int orderNumber = 0;
        int orderQuan = 0;
        double subTotal = 0.0;

        //Beginning of calls to methods
        displayMenu();
        getItemNumber(orderNumber);
        getQuantity(orderQuan);
        computeSubTotal(orderNumber, orderQuan, subTotal);
        discountCheck(subTotal);
    }

    public static void displayMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("\nHere is our menu: \n" + "\n 1. Coffee $1.50" + "\n 2. Latte   $3.50" + "\n 3. Cappuccino  $3.25" + "\n 4. Espresso    $2.00");
    }

    public static int getItemNumber(int orderNumber)    //prompts user for item number (1 for coffee, 2 for latte, etc...)
    {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the item number: ");
        orderNumber = user_input.nextInt();

        final double Coffee = 1.50;
        final double Latte = 3.50;
        final double Cappuccino = 3.25;
        final double Espresso = 2.00;
        double Cost = 0;

        if (orderNumber == 1)
            Cost = Coffee;
        if (orderNumber == 2)
            Cost = Latte;
        if (orderNumber == 3)
            Cost = Cappuccino;
        if (orderNumber == 4)
            Cost = Espresso;

        return orderNumber;
    }

    public static int getQuantity(int orderQuan)
    {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the quantity: ");
        orderQuan = user_input.nextInt();
        return orderQuan;
    }

    public static double computeSubTotal(int orderNumber, int orderQuan, double subTotal)
    {
        subTotal = (orderNumber * orderQuan);
        System.out.print("Your total before discount and tax is: $" + subTotal);
        return subTotal;
    }

    public static boolean discountCheck(double subTotal)    //takes subtotal and returns true if user earned a discount (over $10)
    {
        if (subTotal >= 10.00)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your methods `getItemNumber`, `getQuantity`, `computeSubTotal` and `discountCheck` all return a value, but you are not storing that return value in your main method.

In addition to that, your `getItemNumber()` method is only storing the cost locally, which is then discarded when the method is finished - the cost should be returned (and the method probably renamed).

You probably should have something like this:

```
//Beginning of calls to methods
displayMenu();
double itemCost = getItemCost();  // was getItemNumber()
orderQuan = getQuantity(orderQuan);
subTotal = computeSubTotal(itemCost, orderQuan);
boolean shouldDiscount = discountCheck(subTotal);
```

Of course, to use an object-oriented approach, the variables should be members of your class, then you wouldn't need to pass or return values - they would be accessible to all methods in the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double computeSubTotal(int orderNumber, int orderQuan, double subTotal)
    {
        subTotal = (orderNumber * orderQuan);
        System.out.print("Your total before discount and tax is: $" + subTotal);
        return subTotal;
    }
```

In your `computeSubTotal` method, you do

```
subTotal = (orderNumber * orderQuan);
```

This is not going to intiailize the variable in the main method; you are re-initializing the parameter variable.

In your main method, you should be doing

```
subTotal = computeSubTotal(orderNum, orderQuan);
```

instead of calling the method without using the return value. You might have noticed that I didn't pass `subTotal` to the method. This is not needed. You can instead re-declare the variable inside the method:

```
public static double computeSubTotal(int orderNumber, int orderQuan)
    {
        double subTotal = (orderNumber * orderQuan);
        System.out.print("Your total before discount and tax is: $" + subTotal);
        return subTotal;
    }
```

This applies to the other variables aswell. Java is `pass-by-value`, so if you pass a value to a method, a new reference is created for the method (when you do `int varName` in your method's parameters when you declare the method)